# Android - Animação, ocultando e exibindo um menu

Tags: android, animação

Estou com um problema para criar uma animação.
Tenho um botão na action bar que ao clicar nele, ou exibe ou esconde uma barra de menu.
Até o momento está exibindo ou escondendo utilizando o GONE e VISIBLE.
Gostaria de adicionar uma animação, esse menu fica logo abaixo da action bar, portanto, ao clicar para esconder o menu, gostaria que ele se movimentasse para cima, escondendo-o. Ao clicar para mostrar o menu, gostaria que ele se movimentasse para baixo, mostrando-o.
Outro problema é que o resto do layout deve acompanhar o movimento que for escolhido.
Alguém sabe de um exemplo para esse problema?
Obrigado!

Comment: Douglas, poderia usar o `ViewPropertyAnimator`, que é bem simples, mas exige que sua API mínima seja 12. Poderia seguir esse [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html) do próprio blog do Android Developers.

Comment: Já tentei, não consegui fazer a animação ficar bem feita...

Comment: Poderia incluir o código que já fez até o momento?

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer uma animação de um componente é bem simples. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
EditText cadastroEdtNome
cadastroEdtNome.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CadastroCliente.this, R.anim.slide_up));
```

Pronto! Agora você só precisa do código XML para as animações. O que eu te enviei é este aqui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

Mas [existem muitos outros na internet](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/), e você pode até criar o seu, se quiser!